# How do we know if a Young Tableau represents $3$ or $\bar{3}$?

Tags: representation-theory, young-tableaux

Dimension three in the title was just an example...In general I want to know for any dimension $d$ and any $\mathsf{SU}(n)$.

I am aware of the rule for tensors; if there are more lower indices than upper indices then it is the barred representation. How do we know for Young Tableaux?